Failed to find out the source of a certain portion of a link
I've created a script in python to scrape certain fields from a webpage. When I use this link in the script, it produces all the data in json format and I can parse it accordingly.
import requests

link = 'https://api-emis.kemenag.go.id/v1/institutions/pontren/public/identity/K1hOenRreVRmaWYwSGVzcERWVFpjZz09'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update(headers)
    res = s.get(link)
    container = res.json()['results']
    account_bank_holder = container['account_bank_holder']
    organizer_name = container['organizer_name']
    print((account_bank_holder,organizer_name))

However, the problem is that I can't figure out where this portion K1hOenRreVRmaWYwSGVzcERWVFpjZz09 at the end of the link is coming from.
This is how I found the link:

Navigate to this website
Select 2023/2024 Genap
Click the first item in the table: ACEH
Then, click the first item in the new table: ACEH SELATAN
Finally, click the first item in the new table: 500311010057

You should have the link by now, ending with the portion I mentioned above.
Question: Where is the portion similar to this K1hOenRreVRmaWYwSGVzcERWVFpjZz09 at the end of the final link coming from?

So, developer has used aes encryption along with base64 encoding.
import base64
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import padding

def aes_encrypt_cbc(plaintext: str) -> str:
    secret_key = b'a2c36eb2w1em50d6665dc5d61a68b400'
    base64_iv = "ZW1pc0Jhc2U2NElWa2V5cw=="
    iv = base64.b64decode(base64_iv)
    cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(secret_key), modes.CBC(iv), backend=default_backend())
    encryptor = cipher.encryptor()
    padder = padding.PKCS7(128).padder()
    padded_plaintext = padder.update(plaintext.encode()) + padder.finalize()
    ciphertext = encryptor.update(padded_plaintext) + encryptor.finalize()
    return base64.b64encode(base64.b64encode(ciphertext).decode().encode()).decode()

institution_id = "175974"
encrypted_text = aes_encrypt_cbc(institution_id)
print("Encrypted: ", encrypted_text)

Note: Initialization Vector and secret key may change in future.!

This is incredible. Thanks a zillion.

I have one question about this: where did you find the secret_key and the base64_iv?

That's good one, it's encrypted and present in js files, decoding will require to follow certain steps.!

The portion at the end of the link, such as K1hOenRreVRmaWYwSGVzcERWVFpjZz09, is likely a dynamic identifier that is being generated by the website's backend system. This string could be a unique session ID, token, or base64-encoded value that corresponds to a specific entity (like an institution or record) in the database. It is used to retrieve detailed information for that specific entity, such as the details about the ACEH SELATAN institution in your example.
In summary, the portion like K1hOenRreVRmaWYwSGVzcERWVFpjZz09 is a dynamic value likely generated by the website's backend based on your selections. You can inspect the page's network traffic to determine how the identifier is constructed and how it is passed from the website to the API request.
import base64
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import padding

def aes_encrypt_cbc(plaintext: str) -> str:
    # Secret key and IV (Initialization Vector) as bytes
    secret_key = b'a2c36eb2w1em50d6665dc5d61a68b400'  # 32 bytes (256-bit key)
    base64_iv = "ZW1pc0Jhc2U2NElWa2V5cw=="  # Base64-encoded IV
    iv = base64.b64decode(base64_iv)  # Decode the IV from base64
    
    # Set up the cipher using AES and CBC mode
    cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(secret_key), modes.CBC(iv), backend=default_backend())
    encryptor = cipher.encryptor()
    
    # Pad the plaintext to be a multiple of the block size (16 bytes for AES)
    padder = padding.PKCS7(128).padder()  # AES block size is 128 bits (16 bytes)
    padded_plaintext = padder.update(plaintext.encode()) + padder.finalize()

    # Encrypt the padded plaintext
    ciphertext = encryptor.update(padded_plaintext) + encryptor.finalize()
    
    # Return the ciphertext as a base64-encoded string
    return base64.b64encode(ciphertext).decode()

# Encrypt the institution ID
institution_id = "175974"
encrypted_text = aes_encrypt_cbc(institution_id)

print("Encrypted: ", encrypted_text)


My question was: Where do I locate the content of the two variables secret_key and base64_iv?
